# RelativeLayout is Overlapped

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having issue in android XML layout , I put custom toolbar at top in the following xml layout, but some how the toolbar is get overlapped by the `Linarlayout` below the toolbar layout, so because of that am unable  to click on toolbar button, because it's behind another layout, please help me in order to bring it at top, without affecting the overall layout of the XML design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/copy"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            style="@style/HomeToolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/content_hamburger"
                style="@style/ImageView.Hamburger"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_90" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:outlineProvider="background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/sec_root">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pagerc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:outlineProvider="background"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="6.5">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_below="@id/pagerc"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:outlineProvider="background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="6.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fab_image_buttonl"
            android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_image_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_shape1"
                android:src="@drawable/stadiumicon"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fab_image_button2l"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab_image_button3l"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_image_button3l"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab_image_button3l"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_image_button2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_shape1"
                android:src="@drawable/resticon"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab_image_button3"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_image_button3"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab_image_button3" />



        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fab_image_button3l"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_image_button4l"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab_image_button4l"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_image_button3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_shape1"
                android:src="@drawable/shopping"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_image_button4"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab_image_button4" />



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fab_image_button4l"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab_image_buttonl"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_image_buttonl"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab_image_buttonl"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_image_button4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_shape1"
                android:src="@drawable/cinema_hall"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab_image_buttonl"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_image_buttonl"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab_image_buttonl" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The design of above layout looks something like this.

[image: The design of above layout looks something like below.]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank's for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 toolbar.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Just removed the container layout of toolbar, and then it worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout stacks all its children above each other, if you do not layout them properly.

Give your first LinearLayout containing the toolbar an id, e.g. android:id="@+id/header" and add android:layout_below="@+id/header" to the second LinearLayout in your RelativeLayout.